# Facebook Marketing API - How to limit the amount of ads from .get_ads()?

Tags: python, api, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to pull insights about my ads on a daily basis.

I am firstly pulling the ad ids by using:

`AdAccount("my ad account id").get_ads()`

But this is pulling every single ad that has run on the account (about 10,000 ads) and therefore it is causing my api call to fail because of call limits.

I want to only pull yesterday's active ads - what is the best way of doing it?

I have tried using the following params in the get_ads function but have had no luck:

`AdAccount("my ad account id").get_ads(params={'status':['ACTIVE']})`

`AdAccount("my ad account id").get_ads(params={'field': 'impressions', 'operator': 'GREATER_THAN', 'value': 0 })`

`AdAccount("my ad account id").get_ads(params={'date_preset':'yesterday'})`

How can I reduce the amount of ad ids that I am querying in my api call?

Answer (score 0):

first of all  there is no reason 'date_preset':yesterday shouldn't work. You should check your code once again. However an alternate solution is to give date as in form of 'since' and 'until'. Here is shown a example how you can do **this.**

```
params = {
        'time_range': {
            'since': str(_date),
            'until': str(_date)},
        'fields': fields,
            'breakdowns': breakdowns,      
            'level': level,
            'export_format':'csv'}

AdAccount('act_'+account_id).get_ads(fields=[AdAccount.Field.id],params=params)
```

This should work for you. at the place of _date you can write your date for both places. This will give you 24 hr data.